# How to pass Linq to SQL types to a function

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-sql, function, parameters

The code below is used in a Linq to SQL solution, and is in the Load event of a form.

It works fine to display an ordered list of people's names, and set the value member to that person's ID.

However, I'm going to be using these 'people' comboboxes a lot, so I'd like to put a sub into my Utility code there is only one line in the form's Load event.

I want to call something like: `Call ComboboBoxPeople(cbo, tblTurnbackMain, ReportedByID)`

The sub would begin like: `Public Sub ComboboxPeople(cbo as Combobox, tbl as 'sometype', fld as 'someothertype')`

What can I use as the parameter types for `tbl` and `fld`?

```
'-- cboReportedBy datasource
Dim LQ = (From p In TurnbackDC.vewPeopleAll, t In TurnbackDC.tblTurnbackMain
    Where p.PeopleID = t.ReportedByID
    Select p.Person, p.PeopleID).Distinct()

Dim LT = From x In LQ
    Order By x.Person
    Select x.Person, x.PeopleID

cboReportedBy.DataSource = LT
cboReportedBy.DisplayMember = "Person"
cboReportedBy.ValueMember = "PeopleID"
```

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: What are the `tbl` and `fld` parameters supposed to mean? And how are they related to the code you posted?

Comment: Don't forget to mark your favorite answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first LINQ query, you are defining an anonymous type. If you want you can put almost the whole code block (both `LQ` and `LT`) in a single method and return LT. Since `LT` contains an `IEnumerable(Of T)` with `T` being an anonymous type, you can let your method simply return an `IEnumerable`, as follows:

```
Public Shared Function GetAllPeople() As IEnumerable
   ' code here
End Function
```

This will work in ASP.NET Web Forms, since Web Forms uses reflection to load the data from members that do define (`Person` and `PeopleID`). However, this approach is a bit fragile, since there is no compile time support. Another option therefore is to define a special `Class` (let's call it `PersonDTO`) that contains two public properties `Person` and `PeopleID` and let that method return an `IEnumerable(Of PersonDTO)` or even better an array of `PersonDTO` objects.